# Tailwind CSS peer-checked styling doesn't work on chrome and safari

Tags: css, tailwind-css, svelte

I have the following radio switch to allow users to choose between two options, using Svelte:

```
    <div class="flex justify-center mt-3 mb-2">
        <div class="inline-flex outline outline-neutral-100 rounded-md">
            <div>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="radio"
                    id="internato"
                    class="sr-only peer"
                    checked
                    on:click={() => {
                        $spotTypeBeforeAPICall = spotTypes.INTERNATO;
                    }}
                />
                <label
                    for="internato"
                    class="cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center py-2 px-3 text-base sm:text-lg peer-checked:bg-neutral-100 peer-checked:text-cyan-900 peer-checked:font-bold hover:font-bold"
                >
                    IFE
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="radio"
                    id="iac"
                    class="sr-only peer"
                    on:click={() => {
                        $spotTypeBeforeAPICall = spotTypes.IAC;
                    }}
                />
                <label
                    for="iac"
                    class="cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center py-2 px-3 text-base sm:text-lg peer-checked:bg-neutral-100 peer-checked:text-cyan-900 peer-checked:font-bold hover:font-bold"
                >
                    IAC
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This looks like this on Firefox and some other browsers:

[image]

However, on chrome and Safari it looks like this:

[image]

**tailwind.config:**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**rollup.config**

```js
    import { spawn } from 'child_process';
    import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
    import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
    import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
    import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
    import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
    import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';

    const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

    function serve() {
        let server;

        function toExit() {
            if (server) server.kill(0);
        }

        return {
            writeBundle() {
                if (server) return;
                server = spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });

                process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
                process.on('exit', toExit);
            }
        };
    }

    export default {
        input: 'public/main.js',
        output: {
            sourcemap: true,
            format: 'iife',
            name: 'app',
            file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            svelte({
                compilerOptions: {
                    // enable run-time checks when not in production
                    dev: !production
                }
            }),
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

            // If you have external dependencies installed from
            // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
            // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
            // consult the documentation for details:
            // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
            resolve({
                browser: true,
                dedupe: ['svelte'],
                exportConditions: ['svelte']
            }),
            commonjs(),

            // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
            // the bundle has been generated
            !production && serve(),

            // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
            // browser on changes when not in production
            !production && livereload('public'),

            // If we're building for production (npm run build
            // instead of npm run dev), minify
            production && terser()
        ],
        watch: {
            clearScreen: false
        }
    };
```

**postcss.config:**

```js
module.exports = () => ({
    plugins: [require("tailwindcss")],
})
```

Comment: What CSS can you see being applied when you inspect through your browsers devtools? Is there some CSS property being used that isn’t supported on some browsers?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only things that are not being applied are the peer-checked:bg-neutral-100 and peer-checked:text-cyan-900